# Add PDF in mail Body with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I would like to add a PDF in Body of mail, not with `AddInlineStringAttachment()` but in body. The goal is to see the pdf without download.
Thank's

Comment: For that you will have to embed a PDF viewer in your e-mail, which doesn't seem to be possible. So your best bet would be converting the PDF into an image or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

So, what you can do is embed the PDF to your the html part of the e-mail, you can do that in several ways.

1 - Using `<object>` tag:

```
<object width="400" height="400" type="application/pdf" data="http://emersonjair.info/files/rf-pibic-2013-Emerson.pdf"></object>
```

2 - Using `<iframe>` tag:

```
<iframe src="http://emersonjair.info/files/rf-pibic-2013-Emerson.pdf"></iframe>
```

3 - Using `<embed>` tag:

```
<embed type="application/pdf" src="http://emersonjair.info/files/rf-pibic-2013-Emerson.pdf">
```

4 - Using PDF.js:

[PDF.js Github page](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)

5 - Using pdf2htmlEX

[pdf2htmlEX Github page](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/)

6 - Here is a similar question:

[Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

PS: The user is gonna download the PDF file anyway, even if he doesn't save it for later.